# imputation via propensity score matching

Tags: logistic, data-imputation, propensity-scores

I have a propensity score matching / data imputation question.

The purpose of the propensity score modeling is to put subjects from 
two different clinical trials on a similar footing so that a key 
clinical measurement from one study can be attributed / imputed to 
the other study.  The goal is NOT to directly compare the two studies, 
so this is a very atypical kind of propensity score usage.

My question to this List is more about data modeling philosophy than
computer syntax &etc.

Here is the data setup:

Dataset A for Clinical Trial A

1. Represents  data from clinical trial A
2. Two arms, ‘ACTIVE’ and ‘PLACEBO’
3. The active drug is the same as with Clinical Trial B
4. The trial design is very similar to Clinical Trial B
5. One measurement is a clinical continuous measure obtained 
     via laboratory assay
6. Number of randomized subjects = 500
7. A subset of the baseline covariates is identical to a subset
     of the baseline covariates in Clinical Trial B

Dataset B for Clinical Trial B

1. Represents data from clinical trial B
2. Two arms, ‘ACTIVE’ and ‘PLACEBO’
3. The active drug is the same as with Clinical Trial A
4. The trial design is very similar to Clinical Trial A
5. Does NOT have the clinical continuous measure that is available
     in Clinical Trial A
6. Number of randomized subjects = 5000
7. A subset of the baseline covariates is identical to a subset
     of the baseline covariates in Clinical Trial A
8. Primary endpoint is time-to-event

Here is the analysis setup:

I have separately split Dataset A and Dataset B into ‘ACTIVE’ and 
‘PLACEBO’ subjects.

For the ‘PLACEBO’ subjects I have entered the baseline covariate subsets
into an appropriate logistic regression procedure.  The outcome variable 
is a factor variable representing Clinical Trial A = ‘Y’, so the estimated
propensity scores are the estimated probabilities that a ‘PLACEBO’ subject 
is from Clinical Trial A.

I then, finally, use the %GMATCH algorithm (posted on Mayo Clinic website,
implementation of the Greedy algorithm) in SAS to match 1-to-many where 
the Clinical Trial A subjects are thought of as ‘case’ subjects and the 
Clinical Trial B subjects are thought of as ‘control’ subjects.

The average number of Clinical Trial B subjects matched to a single Clinical
Trial A subject is approximately 5.

I have done a similar analysis for the ‘ACTIVE’ subjects.

Here is my question:

At the end, I will combine the Clinical Trial B matched ‘PLACEBO’ and 
‘ACTIVE’ subjects and perform a Cox PH regression to compare ‘PLACEBO’ 
and ‘ACTIVE’ – there will be no Clinical Trial A subjects in this 
analysis.  I want to incorporate the clinical continuous measurement 
“borrowed” from Clinical Trial A as a covariate.

When doing this, how should I best take into account the 1-to-many 
matching?  Do I need to weight the Clinical Trial B subjects, or can I simply 
enter the matched Clinical Trial B subjects into a Cox PH regression and 
ignore the 1-to-many issue?